# How to upload image from Objective-C to MySQL through CakePHP

Tags: php, objective-c, cakephp, upload, afnetworking

I am making iPhone apps related with CakePHP and MySQL.
Now, I am so confused because I can't upload image through Objective-C and CakePHP to MySQL. I can upload textfield's text below [mail], [password], [name], but I can't upload image to MySQL calam "image". Here is my code.
I think I should make CakePHP's upload method for uploading image.
May I ask how do you think ?

■Version Info
   ・iOS 8.0
   ・CakePHP 2.5.5

■Objective-C

```
 -(void) upload{
 NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(entryArray[@"img"]);

 NSString *url = @"http://localhost/cakephp2.5.5/my_sample_datas/add";
  AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
  manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer new];
  NSMutableURLRequest *request =
  [manager.requestSerializer multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                URLString:url
                                               parameters:@{
                   @"mail": self.entryArray[@"email"],
                   @"password": md5Pass,
                   @"name":  @"HogeMan",
                   }
     constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
                   [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData
                   name:@"image"
                   fileName:@"upload.jpg"
                   mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
           }
```

■CakePHP(MySampleDatasController.php)

```
public function add() {
// About Layout
$this->layout = "Sample";
$this->set("header_for_layout", "Sample Application");
$this->set("footer_for_layout", 
    "TEST");
// About Post
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
  $this->MySampleData->save($this->request->data);
 }
}
```

■MySQL's calam
      [NAME]             [TYPE]
      id                 int(4)
      name               varchar(100)
      mail               varchar(100)
      password           varchar(100)
      image              mediumblob
      fileName           varchar(50)

Comment: Are you sure to save image in mysql ?
you can save it in directory & just save the url of image in mysql with this way you should send two request to your server 1) send information 2)send file

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I am not sure this part. "you should send two request to your server 1) send information 2)send file"  What is this meaning ? Should I add two request in Objective-C and how ?

Comment: I think "1)send Information" is "formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData" and "send file" is "upload.jpg", right ?

Comment: yes, you should first send your form data to your cakephp action & after that send second request that have imagefile within to save image.